# Is this possible to do with Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-custom-search

I am planing on using Google Custom Search and I was wondering if it is possible to return pagemap attributes count? We have on every article page attribute "Category" and we want to display all found article categories and number of results found in each. Like this: Books (10), Electronics (32), Food (14) etc..
Is this possible because I didn't find any documentation on it?